# Limit of function defined by expectation

Tags: integration, statistics, limits, probability-theory, functions

Given $c,\sigma,\tau$ are positive real constants and define a function $f:(-1,1)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{equation}
f(\rho)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{2\pi\sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}\sigma\tau}(-c \vee xy\wedge c)e^{\frac{\sigma^2x^2-2\rho\sigma\tau xy+\tau^2y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma^2\tau^2}}.
\end{equation}
Note that we can see $f$ as $E(-c \vee XY\wedge c)$ for some random variables $(X,Y)^T$ with $(X,Y)^T\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ where 
\begin{equation}
\Sigma=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2 & \rho\sigma\tau\\
\rho\sigma\tau & \tau^2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

I'd like to know the limit of $f$ when $\rho\to\pm1$. I have proved that $f$ is strictly increasing, but I don't what the value of the limit. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\rho=1$, $X=\sigma Z$ and $Y=\tau Z$ where $Z$ is standard normal hence $XY\gt0$ almost surely and $f(1)=E(\sigma\tau Z^2\wedge c)=\sigma\tau \cdot g(\sqrt{c/(\sigma\tau)})$ where, for every positive $a$, $g(a)=E(Z^2\wedge a^2)$. Note that $g(a)=1+2(a^2-1)(1-\Phi(a))-2a\mathrm e^{-a^2/2}/\pi$.

For every $\rho$, if the covariance matrix of $(X,Y)$ is $\Sigma$ then  the covariance matrix of $(X,-Y)$ is $\Sigma$ with the same $\sigma$ and $\tau$ but with $-\rho$ replacing $\rho$.

Hence, 
$f(-\rho)=E(-c\vee-XY\wedge c)=-E(-c\vee XY\wedge c)=-f(\rho)$. In particular $f(-1)=-\sigma\tau\cdot g(\sqrt{c/(\sigma\tau)})$.

Comment: Great +1. Thanks @Did. By the way, in conclusion, can we say that $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$? Of course in the sense right continuous at $-1$ and left continuous at $1$.

Comment: Yes, by coupling of $Y$ for every $\rho$ and by domination, the function $\rho\mapsto f(\rho)$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Coupling of $Y$? What is it? I wonder because you defined the limit using "clever" way. I mean that it doesn't use a natural way by looking the original function. So, how can wee see the continuity easily?

Comment: By realizing $Y$ with $(X,Y)$ having the desired distribution for every $\rho$ simultaneously, as $Y=\rho\tau X/\sigma+(1-\rho^2)^{1/2}\tau Z$ where $Z$ is standard normal and independent of $X$. Then almost sure convergences when $\rho$ varies are available.